# Hide annotations in google bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am displaying a google bar chart based on array of arrays.It currently shows all value with annotation outside.  How do i hide 0 values and show annotation inside bar and remove stem. Data i am using is dynamic so it would be best if i can make function to check for 0 and replace with null inside data view but i would still need stringify to show annotation.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
res=[["Bob",80,0,0],["tom",0,60,0]]
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
tmp=[['Name','percent1','percent2','percent3']].concat(res)
console.log(tmp)
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(tmp);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 2,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                        3,{ calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 3,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       ]);

var options = {
          chart: {
            title: chartTitle,
            
          },
          bars: 'horizontal',
          bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        };
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(chartName));
chart.draw(view, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using the stringify function, we can provide our own function.
if the value is zero, return null. if non-zero, return the formatted value...

```
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 1);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
```

and for the series columns, the same, just return the actual value.
so instead of including the column index, we use the same calc function.

```
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 1);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return val;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  type: data.getColumnType(1),
  label: data.getColumnLabel(1)
```

e.g.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 1);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return val;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  type: data.getColumnType(1),
  label: data.getColumnLabel(1)
}, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 1);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  type: "string",
  role: "annotation"
}, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 2);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return val;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  type: data.getColumnType(2),
  label: data.getColumnLabel(2)
}, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 2);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  type: "string",
  role: "annotation"
}, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 3);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return val;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  type: data.getColumnType(3),
  label: data.getColumnLabel(3)
}, {
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var val = dt.getValue(row, 3);
    if (val !== 0) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  type: "string",
  role: "annotation"
}]);
```

and if you don't want to repeat all the column definitions,
you can build dynamically, based on the columns in the data table...

```
var columns = [0];
for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  addColumn(i);
}

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns(columns);

function addColumn(index) {
  columns.push({
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var val = dt.getValue(row, index);
      if (val !== 0) {
        return val;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
    type: data.getColumnType(index),
    label: data.getColumnLabel(index)
  });
  columns.push({
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var val = dt.getValue(row, index);
      if (val !== 0) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, index);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  });
}
```

Comment: hope this helps, as for annotation placement. you chart needs to allow enough room for the annotation to appear inside the bar. you can try the `annotations` option and reduce the font, etc. but there is no option to force inside the bar. if you need more help here, please provide a sample of the data...